# Multiple integral vector notation

Tags: notation, multiple-integral

I was reading a state estimation book and encountered the axiom of total probability written in this form $$\int_{\mathbf{a}}^{\mathbf{b}} p(\mathbf{x}) \,d\mathbf{x}=\int_{a_N}^{b_N}\dots \int_{a_2}^{b_2}\int_{a_1}^{b_1}p(x_1,x_2,\dots ,x_N)dx_1dx_2\dots dx_N$$ where $\mathbf{a} = (a_1,a_2,\dots,a_N)$, $\mathbf{b} = (b_1,b_2,\dots,b_N)$, $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N)$. I understand the axiom of total probability, but I'm having trouble understanding how the vector notation on the LHS describes the multiple integral on the RHS.

Comment: It doesn't "describe" it, it just abbreviates it this way by convention.

Comment: It's not quite a vector in this notation, it's representing an $N$-dimensional region. If you look up notations for surface integrals, in particular, you'll see something quite similar, e.g. $\int_S f(x, y) dA$ where $dA$ is an infinitesimal area over a surface $S$.

Comment: It's just an unfortunate notation, not meant to be a vector although it looks like one. A more common notation is $d^Nx,$ but then there is instead a discrepancy between boldface $\mathbf{x}$ and italic $x$ which both denote the same variable.

Comment: @ConMan I'm familiar with that notation and I've seen $dA = dx dy$ and it makes sense to me. I imagined $d\mathbf{x}$ as $\Delta \mathbf{x}$ being infinitesimally small but here it seems that $d\mathbf{x}=dx_1dx_2\dots dx_N$.